# Neo4j group by floating point number

Tags: neo4j, group-by, cypher

I have items (cells) with floating point numbers associated with them (gene expression values) and I need `Neo4j` to return me `counts` of the items for the specified range of these floating point numbers. I want to get something like this:

```
cell count: 20
expression: [0, 0.1)

cell count: 25
expression: [0.1, 0.2)

cell count: 10
expression: [0.2, 0.3)
```

Having the data stored in the database in the following way:

```
(c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g.Gene)
ex.expr - expression value; g.geneName - gene name that is set for this query
```

Right now I am stuck with the following query:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene {geneName:"Ifnar1"})
RETURN ex.expr, count(c) as cellcount
```

I need to somehow specify the `range` for each `ex.expr` values individually.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

Sample dataset:

```
g.geneName = "Ifnar1"

c.cellId = 1, ex.expr = 0.05
c.cellId = 2, ex.expr = 0.07
c.cellId = 3, ex.expr = 1.50
c.cellId = 4, ex.expr = 1.21
c.cellId = 5, ex.expr = 2.11
c.cellId = 6, ex.expr = 0.85
c.cellId = 7, ex.expr = 0.96
c.cellId = 8, ex.expr = 0.15

Answer:
[0, 0.5], 3
[0.5, 1.0], 2
[1.0, 1.5], 2
[1.5, 2.0], 0
[2.0, 2.5], 1
```

> Update: Clarifications

Yes, they are of the same length. I want to be able to specify the interval step, say, 0.02, and generate the intervals with this step then, from 0.02, say up to the max, which is 2.5. I know only that the min is `0`, but I do not know the max beforehand actually. No, for the particular task I am doing it, returning intervals for zero counts is not necessary, but it would still be nice if it can be done in general case. How I want to pass the list of intervals? Something like `range` generation, however, I do not know the max, so the max should somehow be determined on the fly `OR` I can just guess the number, that would work too. I expect the distribution of counts to be of normal distribution, so if the expression is too high, the count will be zero.

Comment: Please, can you share a sample data set and the expected result? Maybe a [Neo4j console](http://console.neo4j.org/).

Comment: It's unclear how you want to pass the list of intervals to the query. Give an example. Are all intervals of equal length? Is it necessary to return an interval in which the count of cells is zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the input parameter is the interval `$step`. And the left border of the first interval is zero. Then for each value of `ex.expr` we can calculate in what interval it is:

```
floor(ex.expr / $step)
```

So we need:

- walk through all relationships
- calculate in what interval they belong
- count their number for each interval
- detach in order of intervals
- and return the result (and calculate the boundaries of intervals)

The concept of the query (`$step` is an input parameter):

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene {geneName:"Ifnar1"})
WITH floor(ex.expr / $step) AS intervalIndex, 
     count(c) AS cellCount 
     ORDER BY intervalIndex ASC
RETURN intervalIndex, 
       cellCount
```

What if we not only want to return the interval number, but also its boundaries:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene {geneName:"Ifnar1"})
WITH floor(ex.expr / $step) AS intervalIndex, 
     count(c) AS cellCount 
     ORDER BY intervalIndex ASC
WITH intervalIndex, cellCount,
     $step * intervalIndex AS leftBoundary,
     $step * (intervalIndex + 1) AS rightBoundary
RETURN intervalIndex, 
       [leftBoundary, rightBoundary] AS intervalBoundaries, 
       cellCount
```

For some step values, the returned interval values will be inaccurate, for example at step 0.2 and intervalIndex is 2 - `[0.4, 0.6000000000000001]` instead of `[0.4, 0.6]`. So, based on the number of digits in the step after the decimal point, we need to calculate the factor of calculation accuracy, and round up to the required number of digits (based on Mark Needham post http://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/05/25/neo4j-cypher-rounding-a-float-value-to-decimal-places/):

```
WITH toInteger(split(toString($step - floor($step)), '.')[1]) AS precision
WITH CASE WHEN precision IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE precision END AS precision
WITH 10 ^ precision AS factor

MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene {geneName:"Ifnar1"})
WITH factor,
     floor(ex.expr / $step) AS intervalIndex, 
     count(c) AS cellCount 
     ORDER BY intervalIndex ASC
WITH intervalIndex, cellCount,
     round(factor * $step * intervalIndex) / factor AS leftBoundary,
     round(factor * $step * (intervalIndex + 1)) / factor AS rightBoundary
RETURN intervalIndex, 
       [leftBoundary, rightBoundary] AS intervalBoundaries, 
       cellCount
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always run successive queries programmatically by using parameters:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene {geneName:"Ifnar1"})
WHERE $lower <= ex.expr < $upper
RETURN COUNT(c)
```

Then it's just a matter of writing a script to generate the *$lower* and *$upper* parameters however you wish.

> Edit

Alternatively, if you know the interval boundaries you can do it like this:

```
MATCH (c:Cell)-[ex:EXPRESSES]->(g:Gene {geneName:"Ifnar1"})
WITH c, (CASE
WHEN 0<=ex.expr<0.5 THEN 0
WHEN 0.5<=ex.expr<1 THEN 1
WHEN 1<=ex.expr<1.5 THEN 2
WHEN 1.5<=ex.expr<2 THEN 3
WHEN 2<=ex.expr<2.5 THEN 4 END) AS interval
RETURN interval, COUNT(c), ORDER BY interval
```